# Excel VBA - Random extra grouping levels

Tags: vba, excel, levels

This is not really an issue that affects the code but rather a question of the table's appearance.
So, the table is the summary of records for income and expenses of different business departments. Let's call each department a type of the record. Each of those types has subtype1. Each subtype1 has subtypes2 and each subtype2 has subtypes3.
So the sample data would be something like this.

```
1, Type1, sum of subtypes1
1.1, Subtype1, sum of subtypes2
1.1.1 Subtype2, sum of subtypes3
1.1.1.1 Subtype3, amount
1.1.1.2 Subtype3, amount
1.2, Subtype1, sum of subtypes2
1.2.1, Subtype2, sum of subtypes3
1.2.1.1, Subtype3, amount
```

Each subtype can have different number of "children subtypes". Children subtypes can't go further than subtype3.

Then I am using VBA script to group the records of the same subtype under their direct parent up to the main type. Everything works fine, I can expand or hide every single level of this structure.
However, logically the group outline on the left side of the table for rows should show 4 levels. Instead it shows 8 levels of groups. First 4 do exactly what you would expect, show or hide respective subtypes while the other 4 levels do absolutely nothing which is also expected because I don't see a reason for them to be there.

Any ideas why extra levels have been created and how to get rid of them?
I might have explained this in a not very clear way so feel free to ask for further information.

Comment: Please show your code. Have you considered using a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through your code in trace mode to watch the groups being set up. (open the VBA window and use the F8 key to loop one line at a time)
This may reveal why the extra groups are being defined and suggest what to change.